# static constant giving error - "does not name a type"

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
static const TextureVertexWithZ gMeshVerticesWithZ[] = {

        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, 1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, -1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, -1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, -1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f),

        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f),

        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, 1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f,1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f),

        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,1.0f),

        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, 1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f, 1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f),

        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f),
        FVWITHZ(1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f),
        FVWITHZ(-1.0f, -1.0f,-2.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f),

 };
```

While compiling, I am getting the error " error: 'TextureVertexWithZ' does not name a type"

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I suppose it means `TextureVertexWithZ` is not declared in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, this means that the compiler doesn't know what `TextureVertexWithZ` is.  Presumably you have forgotten to include the header file that declares it.